# Storing and querying time intervals in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Modeling shift planning app:

I came up with such data structure describing the `shift`.

```
{
    "fromHour" : 7,
    "fromMinute" : 30,
    "toHour" : 9,
    "toMinute" : 30,
    "week" : 5,
    "date" : "2015-01-26",
    "user" : {
       // ...
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d0e4a82b9dc26c0c0f36e7")
}
```

The main thing that I need to store is the information:
1. when shift starts (hour and minute), 
2. when shift ends (hour and minute) and 
3. what date it's actually happening.

The fields `fromHour`, `fromMinute`, `toHour`, `toMinute` and `date` as ISO string worked pretty good for me for storing and querying the shifts by particular date.

The problem occurred when I needed to build reports out of it. Say, I want to get all shifts from "2015-01-01" to "2015-02-01" in range from 07:00, till 23:00.

I can add `$and` clause to my query, like

```
[ { fromHour: { '$gte': 7 } },
  { fromMinute: { '$gte': 0 } },
  { toHour: { '$lt': 23 } },
  { toMinute: { '$lt': 0 } } ]
```

But that doesn't work good, since for shift there `toMinute` is 30 the `$lt` will be false.

I'm trying to find efficient data structure that would allow to store timespans that would be easy to query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing hours and minutes in two different fields separated is too error-prone and makes your job harder. Since Mongo does not have a distinct "Time" data type, only Date, and shifts usually start and end at "easy" times, I would recommend to implement something like converting the time to a real number in your application like this:

```
00:00 --> 0
01:00 --> 1
...
08:00 --> 8
08:15 --> 8.25
08:30 --> 8.5
...
16:30 --> 16.5
...
```

It is a bit of extra work in the app because you have to convert while saving or displaying but it's still better than having one single time value in two different fields.

So your data would look like this:

```
{
    "shiftStart" : 7.5,
    "shiftEnd" : 9.5,
    "week" : 5,
    "date" : "2015-01-26",
    "user" : {
       // ...
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d0e4a82b9dc26c0c0f36e7")
}
```

and your query:

```
[ { shiftStart: { '$gte': 7 } },
  { shiftEnd: { '$lt': 23 } } ]
```

Comment: I actually was thinking about something similar, but was not really sure if this is good idea.. thx a lot for you suggestion.

Comment: If you decide to go with this solution, a fairly simple system for getting the number you want to put in is: `( ( Date.UTC(<year>,<month>,<day>,<hour>,<min>,<sec>) / 1000 ) % 86400 ) / 3600`. That should get the UNIX timestamp `mod` by the number of seconds in a day and then divided by the number of seconds in an hour.

Comment: @NoOutlet it seems to be, the simplest would be `fromHour + fromMinute / 60.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data with the date type in `ISODate(...)` format and then use [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and [Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to query the data.

For your example:

```
db.shifts.aggregate([
  { $match:  //matches the dates first to filter out before $project step
    { datetimeStart:
      { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      },
      datetimeEnd:
      { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  { $project:  // $project step extracts the hours
    { otherNeededFields: 1,  // any other fields you want to see
      datetimeStart: 1,
      datetimeEnd: 1,
      hourStart: { $hour: "$datetimeStart" },
      hourEnd: { $hour: "$datetimeEnd" }
    }
  },
  { $match: // match the shift hours
    { hourStart: { $gte: 7 },
      hourEnd: { $lte: 23 }
    }
  }
])
```

With this system it would be **possible**, but **complicated** to find something more like shifts between 7:30AM and 10:30PM:

```
db.shifts.aggregate([
  { $match:  //matches the dates first to filter out before $project step
    { datetimeStart:
      { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T07:30:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      },
      datetimeEnd:
      { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T07:30:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  { $project:  // $project step extracts the hours
    { otherNeededFields: 1,  // any other fields you want to see
      datetimeStart: 1,
      datetimeEnd: 1,
      hourStart: { $hour: "$datetimeStart" },
      minStart: { $minute: "$datetimeStart" },
      hourEnd: { $hour: "$datetimeEnd" },
      minEnd: { $minute: "$date
    }
  },
  { $match: // match the shift hours
    { $or:
      [
        {hourStart: 7, minStart: {$gte: 30}}, // hour is 7, minute >= 30
        {hourStart: { $gte: 8 }}  // hour is >= 8
      ],
      $or:
      [
        {hourEnd: 22, minEnd: {$lte: 30}}, // hour is 22, minute <= 30
        {hourEnd: { $lte: 21 }} // hour is <= 21
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: this is just great answer.. indeed, cases 7:30 / 22:30 are actual. however, the compexity of the solution is something that make it less attractive. I'm going to try solution by @Laszlo Tenki if find a problem there, will get back here.